# React steps app, wizard with data between steps forms

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm new to react and I'm developing a wizard app that collects data from each step and finally uses that data to generate a report.

I used 1 parent component and then attached the steps as childs, but now I read data can only flow down and I dont know how to get the data back from the steps to make the operations.

Flow looks like this :

```
<StepsForm>
  <StepOne/>
  <StepTwo/>
  <StepThree/>
</StepsForm>
```

Do I need to go vertical?

```
<StepsForm>
  <StepOne>
     <StepTwo>
        <StepThree/>
     </StepTwo>
  </StepOne>
```

With 3 steps sounds good but if I add more steps in the future will be a mess, and app is already working with horizontal flow.

I'm working over this example: https://ant.design/components/steps/

Only replaced content strings with components.

Just tried passing state as child prop and then modifing from child but didnt work.

Any help is appreaciated.

Chunks of my code:

FormComponent

```
constructor() {

    super();
    this.state = {
      customers: [],
      selectedCustomer: "",
    };
  }

<StepOne customers={this.props.customers} selectedCustomer={this.state.selectedCustomer} />
```

StepOne

```
export default class StepOne extends Component {
  setClient(value, option){
    this.props.selectedCustomer = "debug" //fails
...  }

 <Select
...   onSelect={this.setClient}
      >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate a lot Mikkel's answer and I will consider using a more robust solution in the future, but by now I had to combine some posts to achieve this.

I needed to change state and do some other things at the same time with Ant Design autocomplete element inside Ant Design Steps.

Key lines are this :

StepsForm.jsx

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      customers: [],
      selectedCustomer: "",
    };
  }
  changeButtonState(event) {
      this.setState({selectedCustomer: event.props.item})
  }

<StepOne 
buttonClick={this.changeButtonState.bind(this)} 
customers={this.props.customers} 
selectedCustomer={this.state.selectedCustomer} />
```

StepOne.jsx

```
   setClient(value, option){
    //doing another stuff 
    const name = option.props.children
  }
  <AutoComplete
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Insert"
    onSelect={(option, value) => this.setClient(option,value,this.props.buttonClick(value)  )}>
    {children}
  </AutoComplete>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is definitely the way to go, the second one will cause even more pain.

Basically you can pass a function down to the children (steps), to update the state (value) in the parent.

A good way to learn about this is to look at how other people have done it. I wrote my own initially, and then found this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stepzilla which I ended up adopting and forking for my own purposes.

Another candidate is this one, which is a little simpler
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-step-wizard.

Using other people's code isn't a bad thing, the important thing is to learn how things work, and sometimes it saves a bunch of work to use or adapt an open source component.

Comment: Thanks! , my last option is using a library because Im using ant design example that manages almost everything. I added some of my code in case you can help. Thanks for your advice,